# Filling SQLite Database with Data Once

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

In my application I use a SQLite `DBhelper` class (extend extends `SqliteOpenHelper`), which overwrites my onCreate, OnUpgrade-methods. Also I need to create a `DBManager`-class to assure a controlled access to my DB from other classes....

Now I want to set up my data for the DB. This data has to be created once at the first start of my app. How can I assure that the data is only created once from `DBManager`? I want to call my methods for setup DB-Data from `DBManager`-class to have clean software design....

Here is a code-example from `DBManager`:

```
public class DBManager {
    private static final String TAG = DBManager.class.getSimpleName();

    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private static Context myContext;
    private static DBManager instance;

    private DBManager() {
        myContext = MyApplication.getAppContext();
        if (myContext == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("MyApplication returned null-Context");
        helper = new DatabaseHelper(myContext);

    }

    public static void init() {
        if (null == instance) {
            instance = new DBManager();
        }
    }

    public static DBManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DBManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    // Some Methods to add Data and Get Data form SQL-Database

    // a Method, which creats my Objects for first App-Start; have to be called once
}
```

Comment: Create a function inside DBManager class that further calls DBHelper class to inserts data into sqlite. Now, when your activity starts call this DBManager class insert function.

Comment: that is not my goal...in your explanation the DB is filled every new activity lifecirle! I want to setup my data only at the first start of my app!

Comment: make a Boolean variable in your activity and set its value to true by default. then, when your activity starts first of all check its value, if it's true call insert method of DBManager class and set value of that Boolean variable to false. Then, each time your activity starts it will check value of that Boolean variable, it will be false each time and your activity will not call to insert function.

Comment: it also the same wrong solution!!!! Next start of my app-> the data of my app is setup again!!

Answer (score 1):

Put you insert statements (or function call that points to your inserts) in the `onCreate` method of your `DBHelper`.  The first time your app runs, the `DBHelper` will recognize that there is no database for the app, and will run the `onCreate` (where you should create your tables and insert seed data).  After that, the `onCreate` should not run again unless the database gets deleted.

Comment: thats also my solution at the moment ;) But in my opinion its a unclean solution! Because i want to handle all DB-Stuff from other classes with my DBManager... I am looking for a solution with the same result, but my data has to insert once from DBManager, because my data are objects from other classes, which i persist with ormlite into DB